# MySQL producing columns with loop in a select statement

Tags: mysql, function, select, loops

In MySQL I have a function that takes a number argument and spits out a subset of results from another table, based on that number. Implementation currently looks like:

```
SELECT 
  id,
  date,
  function(do stuff with value 1) as t1,
  function(do stuff with value 2) as t2,
  function(do stuff with value 3) as t3,
  ...
  function(do stuff with value N) as tN
FROM table
```

Can you use a loop in a select statement (or even a procedure that builds a table) so the above becomes:

```
SELECT
  id,
  date,
  LOOP x = 1 through N
    function(do stuff with value x) as tx,
  END LOOP
FROM table
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is this select statement part of a larger project? Have you considered using a loop in the calling language(php, java, etc) to generate the string for the select statement?

Comment: I'm trying to do as much of this inside MySQL as possible - both for the project, and my learning. Ideally the query will be selected into a table for use further down the road.

Comment: so you're trying to dynamically select n + 2 columns with only sql? I don't know if it's possible. Do you have any of the query so far or are you just trying to see if it's possible before you start? I don't think it is and googling hasn't gotten me any closer to finding a solution.

Comment: Yup - I (think) I exhausted google before coming here... I've written the query longhand (or rather generated it outside MySQL and pasted it in) but was curious if it was possible within MySQL

Comment: Here are the only functions that modify the flow of control, but I don't see any looping functions.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/control-flow-functions.html

Comment: This is interesting, but I still don't think it's going to lead to a solution.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/loop-statement.html

Comment: Got it... barring embedding it in the select itself, what are MySQL's capabilities for this in a stored procedure? Such as can I build the query statement in a loop saved into a variable then call that variable? It might be asking a lot - but fun to think about, ya?

Comment: ehh, sounds like we're trying to force a square peg into a round hole. I'm going to get some breakfast, good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes you can... take a look into DynamicSQL..

[Here's one sample](http://rpbouman.blogspot.com/2005/11/mysql-5-prepared-statement-syntax-and.html)

[and another example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/SQL/Procedure-Function/EXECUTEdynamicSQLcommand.htm)

In general, you build a string that contains the SQL statement you want to execute, then prepare it, then execute it...