# Cakephp get all months records with a single query i.e with single find

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp-2.0

I am working on a ecommerce with platform cakephp and using google charts for reports.My requirement is to get all records as per all 12 months, so I have used following code for a single month

**Query**

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM orderproductmasters AS Orderproductmaster 
    LEFT JOIN ordermasters AS Ordermaster ON 
        (Orderproductmaster.ordermaster_id = Ordermaster.id) LEFT JOIN productmasters AS Productmaster ON 
        (Orderproductmaster.productmaster_id = Productmaster.id) 
        WHERE Ordermaster.orderstatusmaster_id = 1 AND Month(Orderproductmaster.created) = 8
```

**Code**

```
 $this->Orderproductmaster->find('count',
        array('conditions'=>array('Ordermaster.orderstatusmaster_id'=>1,'
            Month(Orderproductmaster.created)'=>8)));
```

Since, I need records as per Jan, feb,march and all 12 months...,so for 12 months I am using following code

```
for($i=1;$i<13;$i++)
{
    $orderproductmasters[$i] = $this->Orderproductmaster->find('count',
        array('conditions'=>array('Ordermaster.orderstatusmaster_id'=>1,
            'Month(Orderproductmaster.created)'=>$i)));
}
```

So question might be silly, but is it possible to get all months record without using for loop i.e, within a single query.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Exactly Which sql query is running on server ?

Comment: SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `orderproductmasters` AS `Orderproductmaster` LEFT JOIN `ordermasters` AS `Ordermaster` ON (`Orderproductmaster`.`ordermaster_id` = `Ordermaster`.`id`) LEFT JOIN `productmasters` AS `Productmaster` ON (`Orderproductmaster`.`productmaster_id` = `Productmaster`.`id`) WHERE `Ordermaster`.`orderstatusmaster_id` = 1 AND Month(`Orderproductmaster`.`created`) = 8

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655614/cakephp-count-items-per-month-in-a-year might work check

Answer (score 0):

```
 $options = array();
    $options['fields'] = array('COUNT(Orderproductmaster.id)'); 
    $options['conditions'] = array('Ordermaster.orderstatusmaster_id = 1',
    'Month(Orderproductmaster.created) BETWEEN 1 AND 12');
    $options['joins'] = array(
                            array(
                            'table' => 'ordermasters',
                            'alias' => 'Ordermaster',
                            'type' => 'left',
                            'conditions' => array(
                                 'Orderproductmaster.ordermaster_id = Ordermaster.id'
                             )
                          ),
                        array(
                            'table' => 'productmasters',
                            'alias' => 'Productmaster',
                            'type' => 'left',
                            'conditions' => array(
                            'Orderproductmaster.productmaster_id = Productmaster.id'                
                           )
                         )
                                                        );
            $options['group'] => array('Month(Orderproductmaster.created)');    
  $this->Orderproductmaster->find('all',$options);
```

Comment: Thanks for response but its not working ,I need output like this which I am getting with for loop  Array
(
    [1] => 0
    [2] => 0
    [3] => 0
    [4] => 0
    [5] => 0
    [6] => 0
    [7] => 0
    [8] => 15
    [9] => 0
    [10] => 0
    [11] => 0
    [12] => 0
)

Answer (score 0):

I think , your need can be fulfilled by using cursors in stored procedure. And then using stored procedure to cake-php.

Example on db side is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8861734/mysql-producing-columns-with-loop-in-a-select-statement)

Answer (score 0):

What About something like:

```
 $this->Orderproductmaster->find('count',
        array(
     'fields'=>'DISTINCT(Month(Orderproductmaster.created)),
     'conditions'=>array('Ordermaster.orderstatusmaster_id'=>1,'
            Month(Orderproductmaster.created)'=>8)));
```